# In poker, What is the chance of a pair?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

While playing poker last night with my housemates I started wondering, "What is the chance of a pair coming up?" (To clarify, at least one pair).

I started solving it like the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem):

- Probability that the first card is not a pair is `1`. (Since two cards are required for a pair).
- $A$: Probability that the second card is not a pair of the 1st card is $\frac{48}{51}$. (Since there are three other cards which could produce a pair)
- $B$: Probability that the third card is not a pair of the 1st or the 2nd is $\frac{44}{50} * A$. (Since there are now 6 cards which could produce a pair).
- $C$: Probability that the fourth card is not a pair of the 1st or the 2nd or the 3rd is $\frac{40}{49} * B * A$
- $D$: Probability that the fifth card is not a pair of the 1st or the 2nd or the 3rd or the 4th is $\frac{36}{48} * C * B * A$
- Therefore the probability that there is a pair given 5 cards is $1 - (\frac{36}{48} . \frac{40}{49} . \frac{44}{50} . \frac{48}{51})$

More generally the probability that there are no pairs with `n` cards is $1 - (\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}{\frac{(52-i) - 3i}{(52 - i)}})$

This morning I found solutions online like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvEMssSpcrM) but they use combinatorics. Is my solution valid? Have I made any mistakes?

Comment: Does four-of-a-kind count as a pair?

Comment: The video you linked is calculating the probability of exactly 1 pair. What you found is the probability that at least two cards in the hand have the same rank, which could mean there's one pair, two pairs, three of a kind, four of a kind. Also note that your formula only works up to $n=13$ because if $n=14$ there must be a pair by the pidgeonhole principle.

Comment: @Henry yes at least one pair to clarify